# Link label with Vertical Separator

Tags: linklabel

How do we achieve vertical separation between LinkLabels. Tried searching in google but all solutions point towards Horizontal separations. For reference please see image [LinkLabels with vertical separation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I10Q.gif)

Comment: Could you give us examples of what you have tried?

Comment: Those are simply "pipes" | | | as a simple label... I think.

Comment: Started out with exact approach as suggested by @Tim, but I need separations among Link labels which can be adjusted with Height of Link label.

Also tried using tool strip control, but it does not contain Link Labels

Comment: Then use a simple bitmap that you scale in the height when needed.